# VBA Validate Combobox Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template in Excel using comboboxes where users will populate from an analysis from a list. There are many to choose from and the user must select the correct one otherwise it will populate incorrect results. I thought it would be nice to add in some error handling so that the user can change any incorrect selection before populating all boxes and running the results.

So I was hoping I would be able to find a code that goes something along the lines of:

```
IF Combobox1.Value NOT LIKE "Europe" THEN

MSGBOX 'Message Inserted Here'
EXIT SUB

ELSE 

CONTINUE WITH MACRO.....
```

and this could be repeated for all comboboxes within the template that need to be populated:

```
IF Combobox2.Value NOT LIKE "Canada" THEN

MSGBOX 'Message Inserted Here'
EXIT SUB

ELSE 

CONTINUE WITH MACRO.....
```

I haven't inserted real code because I'm not sure if this exists in VBA, I'm just drawing on my SQL experience here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `Private Sub Combobox1_Change()` and put validation code there.

Comment: Thanks omegastripes but this did not work. I entered - Private Sub Combobox1_Change(IF Combobox1.Value NOT LIKE "Europe" THEN MsgBox"The Analysis Selected is wrong" Exit Sub END IF) but got a Compile error: Expected identifier

Comment: Use `InStr()` to check if a string contains a substring, or regex pattern `\bEurope\b` to check if a string contains a word.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. If you put your code in the worksheet you don't have to fully qualify the reference. But if the code is placed in a module the reference must be fully qualified. It is a best practice to place code into modules.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1.Text <> "Europe" Then
    MsgBox "The Analysis Selected is wrong"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks GMalc, I think this is so close however it looks like its saying not equal too. Ideally I want to find something in VBA that not like as the analysis name will always be different but will contain the region name hence trying to read part of the string to look for Europe. I'm not sure if that's even possible in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, with your help I managed to get it to work:

```
Dim MsgBoxResult As Long

If InStr(1, Combobox.Column(1), "Europe") = 0 Then

MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("The following analysis does not match the region is this correct?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

    If MsgBoxResult = vbNo Then
        End

    Else

    End If

End If
```